# How to write a floating number to a text file? (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python3, and I've started working on a program. It is a finance calculator. I'm working with floating numbers (for the dollars and the cents). I have a separate .txt document (history.txt) that the program is referring to throughout the code. One of the first things is taking the user's money and saving it to a text file.

I tried using the *file.write()* command, but it said that the argument had to be a str, not a float.

```py
import os
cash = float(input("How much cash did you earn?"))
history = open("history.txt","w+")
if os.stat("history.txt").st_size == 0:
    history.write(cash)
```

Here is the error that I received.

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not float

Comment: To convert to string just use `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `format` from string:

```
import os
cash = float(input("How much cash did you earn?"))
history = open("history.txt","w+")
if os.stat("history.txt").st_size == 0:
    history.write("%f\n" % cash)
```

also try to handle your file this way:

```
with open("history.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.write("line to append to file")
```

Comment: This worked well. I ended up just saying ```f.write("%f\n" % cash)``` . However, it only outputs to the first line of the text box and replaces it. I'm trying to have it record line after line, instead of just replacing it.

Comment: Try with the second snippet, it opens the file in append mode, note the **'a'**. Also you can explore other possibilities for formatting https://pyformat.info/.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
cash = float(input("How much cash did you earn?"))
history = open("history.txt","w+")
if os.stat("history.txt").st_size == 0:
    history.write(str(cash))
    history.close()
```